# Clase fecha contructor por copia

Tags: c++

¿Cómo puedo realizar un contructor por copia?
Tengo un contructor por defecto y necesito uno por copia, aun no tengo una idea clara de como hacerlo, me podrian brindar la estructura y la explicación de la misma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un constructor copia es aquel que recibe un parámetro como referencia constante del mismo tipo que la clase definida:

```
struct S
{
    S();          // Constructor por defecto
    S(const S &); // Constructor copia
    S(S &&);      // Constructor de movimiento
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Para declararlo lo hago como en el constructor por defecto?

Comment: Para declarar un constructor de copia, simplemente crea un constructor que recibe un único parámetro como referencia constante del mismo tipo que la clase definida.